# How can I limit an entity reference selection to a specific field value on the reference

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a content type `Research` which has a an entity reference type of `People`.

The problem is that I don't want to show ALL people but only people which have a certain value under their field named `type`.
I was trying to find it here:
[image]
Anyone an idea how to only show a content-type for a certain field value of that content type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a view display with type `Entity Reference` (from an existing view or a new one - it's up to you) then add filters to filter out the people you want to display.
   [image]
2. In your setting field screen, select `Reference method` as `Views` then select the view display you just created from the list below.
   [image]

**You can refer to detailed instructions here:** https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-entity-reference-view/

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new "entity reference" view via the views interface that outputs the "people" that you want to be able to reference.
2. Alter the "reference method" on the page in the screenshot above to reference the view you just created.